# Laravel Eloquent Paginate Doesn't Exist Error

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

I'm trying to set pagination in a Laravel blade/view but it's showing an error with this message below:

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

*Controller*

```
public function view()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $basic_info = User::find($user->id)->basic_info;
    $category = Category::all()->paginate(10); 

    return view('admin.article.category-view')->with(['user' => $user, 'basic_info' => $basic_info, 'category' => $category]);
}
```

*View Blade* (admin.article.category-view)

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($category as $cat)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $cat->name }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $category->links() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `all()`:

```
 $category = Category::paginate(10);
```

When you're using `all()` you get all the rows from the table and get a collection

You can only invoke `"paginate"` on a `Query`, not on a `Collection`.

Comment: It worked. Now I can understand how collections work. Thanks a lot for enlightening me.

Answer (score 5):

Using paginate method on the query builder or an Eloquent query only, not on collection, like so:

```
public function view()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $basic_info = User::find($user->id)->basic_info;
    $category = Category::paginate(10); 

    return view('admin.article.category-view')->with(['user' => $user, 'basic_info' => $basic_info, 'category' => $category]);
}
```